# Comparing two instance variables in java

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two instances of objects

a. Create a Superhero named Cyclops

```
Superhero Cyclops = new Superhero("Cyclops");
```

b. Create a Superhero named Colossus. Colossus has a strength of 40

```
Superhero Colossus = new SuperHero("Colossus", 40);
```

The first instance of the object called Cyclops has a default value of 10, and the second object is already assigned a value of 40, this is their strength value within the code.

How would I make a fight method that would take into consideration their strengths and then determine the winner?

The code for the Superhero class is displayed below

```
public class Superhero{

    //private instance variables declared below
    //name of the super hero
    private String name;
    //name of the strength variable
    private int strength;
    //The variable for the powerUp method
    private int powerUp;
    //variable to store the power of the power up
    private int storePower;



    //getter and setter methods.
    public int getStrength(){
        return strength;
    }




    /*
    This method takes in an integer paremeter and based on that it does
    some calculations.

    There are four possible integer values you can pass in: 100, 75, 50 and 25.

    If 100 has been passed in the storePower variable is set to 40 which would be
    a power-up of 40, if 75 then power-up of 30, if 50 then a power-up of 20,
    if 25 then a power-up of 10 and if the right ammount is not specified a power-up
    of 0 will be assigned.

    */
    public int powerUp(int powerUp){
        this.powerUp = powerUp;
        if(powerUp == 100){
            storePower = 40;
        }else if(powerUp == 75){
            storePower = 30;
        }else if(powerUp == 50){
            storePower = 20;
        }else if(powerUp == 25){
            storePower = 10;
        }else{
            storePower = 0;
        }
        strength = strength + storePower;
        System.out.println("After receiving a power-up: " + name +  " has a Strength of: " + strength);
        return strength;

    }

    public void fight(){


    }


    //constructor for if the player wanted to specify the name and the strength
    public Superhero(String name, int strength){
        this.name = name;
        this.strength = strength;

        System.out.println(name + " " + strength);
    }



    //if the user doesn't enter the strength as it is optional
    //this constructor below will run and set the default
    public Superhero(String name){
        this.name = name;
        strength = 10;
        System.out.println(name + " " + strength );

    }

}
```

and as you can see public void fight, is empty as that's the method I am trying to create.

also the main method of the fight class is displayed below

```
public class Fight{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // a. Create a Superhero named Cyclops
        Superhero Cyclops = new Superhero("Cyclops");

        //b. Create a Superhero named Colossus. Colossus has a strength of 40
        Superhero Colossus = new SuperHero("Colossus", 40);

        Cyclops.fight(Cyclops.getStrength(), Colossus.getStrength());

        //d. Give Cyclops a powerUp of 100
        Cyclops.powerUp(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the fact that you powerup Cyclops after the fight important in any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating attack for java game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182412/generating-attack-for-java-game).

Comment: Yes the power up is to add extra strength bonus to the Cyclops, so if the user entered 100 for the powerup the Cyclops would get 40 strength bonus

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how on earth is this a duplicate of that post?

Comment: It would be much more useful if you describe a little bit of action.  Now you have superheroes which are supposed to fight each other but none of them know what that means.  It may have something to do with strength but it may also be the one who counts fastest from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a hero by parameter as you have on the other methods, and return the winner of the battle:

```
 public SuperHero fight(SuperHero opponent) {
      if (this.getStrength() > opponent.getStrength())
           return this
      return opponent;
 }
```

So you can have on the main call:

```
 SuperHero winner = cyclope.fight(colossus);
 System.out.println("The winner is: " + winner);
```

This problem helps you to understand how to think about the problems. You have here a SuperHero class and you want to let the SuperHeros fight, as you know, a fight have a winner, so the return of the function can be the winner of the battle. On the class body you are creating the behaviour of the instance that is accessed via the `this` keyword\variable, so you just need the opponent that `this` hero will fight against, creating a `SuperHero opponent` parameter is a good way. Comparing the strength values you are finding the winner and returning it. You can improve the things and add more attributes to compare, also, define a behavior when the SuperHeros have the same strength, would be great if you can do a random choice.

Just one more advice, look at the name of my variables, they start with a lowercase letter, it's a Java convention and you should care about that, it helps you to read your code.

Comment: Cyclops 10
Colossus 40
The winner is: Superhero@6d06d69c
After receiving a power-up: Cyclops has a Strength of: 50

Comment: why is the error happening: The winner is: Superhero@6d06d69c

Comment: That's not an error.  That's the default `toString` method.  If you want the *name* of the winner, you'll need to ask the object for it by calling an appropriate method (such as a `getName` method)

Comment: You can override the `toString` method and define the return you want. Java by default prints the class name plus a @ signal plus the `hashCode` method's return. Inspect the code of the `Object` class and you can see how it's done. To override a method just define it as the same signature of the parent class method, like `public String toString() { <your code here> }`

Comment: I have looked into overriding however I cannot get my head around it, for my code is there a way to implement the override, can you show an example of this?

Comment: You can search for this here on Stack Overflow, and if, and only if, you cannot find a question about that, ask a new one, the rule is, one question by question, sorry (:

Comment: @user5438578 there's nothing to it, `public String toString() { return this.name; }`, but Jean makes a good point - you need to make a new post for each new question.